# Incorrect parameter type for operator '&'. Expected Text, received Number (Related field: Formula)

Tags: formula

I have Pin field which is a formula field and PIN should be DDMM part of DOB of customer.

I have written a foll formula and it gives error

```
DAY( Customer_id__r.Date_of_Birth__c )  & MONTH(Customer_id__r.Date_of_Birth__c)
```

and the error is

Incorrect parameter type for operator '&'. Expected Text, received Number (Related field: Formula)

Can some one help pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` concatenation operator expects the left operand and right operand to be text. But `DAY(Customer_id__r.Date_of_Birth__c)` returns integer and so throws syntax error.

You can surround the DAY and MONTH functions with TEXT() function like

```
TEXT(DAY(Customer_id__r.Date_of_Birth__c)) & TEXT(MONTH(Customer_id__r.Date_of_Birth__c))
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should use like this

```
text(day(Customer_id__r.Date_of_Birth__c)) +'&' + text(month(Customer_id__r.Date_of_Birth__c))
```